# how to access and view log file in android smartphone(device)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I create a very simple Android app by using Android studio, I can run it successfully in Studio, It is a simple query button and after press the button to submit, It will show text message in TextView. like some news from Fox,

I tested many times in Studio all success, but when I installed and deployed in Android smartphone device, It displayed the UI  but when I press the button, it crashed.
I hope to see log file in android smartphone,

1. where is log file ?
2. what is name of log file??
3. Use what tool to access and view log file??

I searched a while, I use Log collector, cannot get crash reason
cannot answer above 3 question,

I can get error like:

> ******02-23 19:52:12.503  6505  6505 D dalvikvm: DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS 02-23 19:52:12.503 
>   6505  6505 W dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 123
>   (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build; 02-23 19:52:12.503  6505  6505
>   D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x01c1 02-23 19:52:12.513 
>   6505  6505 I dalvikvm: Could not find method
>   android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method
>   com.mxtech.app.AppUtils.a 02-23 19:52:12.513  6505  6505 W dalvikvm:
>   VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 266:
>   Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable
>   (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; 02-23 19:52:12.513  6505  6505
>   D dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008******

It did not advice any crash root reason like Studio running window can tell so details

Please help

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Just keep your devie connected via USB and all the logs will be displayed in the log cat. For a detailed usage guide refer to: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**Apologies** for the crudeness of the image.

If you're looking for the stack trace in Android Studio, or what was known as the LogCat in Eclipse, you can look towards the bottom of your screen for the Android Monitor. All `Log.*()` calls end up there.

If it's not there on your taskbar, follow **View -> Tool Windows -> Android Monitor**

[image: Screenshot of LogCat]

Answer (score 0):

run your app and dont disconnect press alt +6 you will see logcat then select error you will see where it is crashing. if you want any device logcat whiout connecting to android device you have to use any analytical tool like crashanalystic(www.fabric.io)use this tool its simple any crash you will get compleate stacktrash in brouser and mail.

Comment: Thanks, Jain,I used the android studio and I can view my log in development  and log is at run tab same as you, but my problem is my app crashed in my cellphone at runtime and I hope to see log in my cellphone

Comment: Yes use crash anlystic toll mad by fabric.io

Comment: I can get any crash in my app in any device in the world

Comment: Jain, Thanks a lot,Is this tool: Crash Analytics Android - NewRelic.com‎??